# I am not getting any list of documents from firestore collection despite of data present

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a MeetinCountries collection which has subcollection as Meeting and furthermore it has subcollection location. I am able to get the list of data from the parent collection(MeetinCountries and Meetings) but whenever i try to fetch the list of data from the location collection , I am getting no any value. I am getting 0 or empty documents when i debug. I have also attached my firestore snapshot.[image]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Place List'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('MeetinCountries')
            .doc(widget.country)
            .collection('Meetings')
          .doc(widget.meeting)
        .collection('location')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          }
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Text('Loading...');
            default:
              List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList = snapshot.data!.docs;
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: documentList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  String church = documentList[index]['place'];
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(church),
                    onTap: () {
                     
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to retrieve data when you use `get()` instead of `snapshot()`?

Comment: I tried with get() but it did not work

Comment: You have to specify the `stream` outside the `streambuilder` as documented [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes) and also avoid using `switch` case and I recommend you to use [collection group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) queries to retrieve values easily.

Comment: Here is code [snippet](https://codefile.io/f/eo5MchBAVx)

Comment: Thank yo so much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are constructing stream under `StreamBuilder`. I recommend you to construct the stream in a private variable then use it under the `StreamBuilder` as documented [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes)
`StreamBuilder` helps you to automatically manage the `streams` state and disposal of the `stream` when it's no longer used within your app. And avoid using `switch` case which has no `break` statement in your case. Use `if` statement instead. And I recommend you to use [collection group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) queries to retrieve values easily. Here is the code snippet:

```
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('location').snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldkey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Help"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _usersStream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text('Something went wrong'),
            );
          }

           if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }
```